# find and replace when pattern include \n - linux command line

Tags: linux, text, replace, sed, awk

I'm have a file where I want to replace a pattern that terminates with end of line `\n`... I've search the web for a way to do this but none of them work... I'm able to replace the end of lines to other things but not a pattern containing the end of the line..

Here's an example
The text file has this:

```
22.0,26235,-48.4,-999,-999,-999,100,22,669.0,-999,669.0
20.0,26860,-47.5,-999,-999,-999,100,21,690.0,-999,690.0
19.3,27096,-47.1,-999,-999,-999,100,21,698.3,-999,698.3
19.0,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,100,21,-999,-999,
```

there is a value missing in the last line (it can be in any other line) and I want to find the, `\n` and replace by a ,`-999`

So the text becomes like this:

```
22.0,26235,-48.4,-999,-999,-999,100,22,669.0,-999,669.0
20.0,26860,-47.5,-999,-999,-999,100,21,690.0,-999,690.0
19.3,27096,-47.1,-999,-999,-999,100,21,698.3,-999,698.3
19.0,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,100,21,-999,-999,-999
```

any ideas ????

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
sed 's/,[^0-9]*$/,-999/' filename
```

Comment: I thought it worked but instead I got a extra ,-999 in every line and in the last line I got ,,-999

=(

I've also tried the awk suggestions but without success

Comment: Oh yes, I believe that you tried `sed 's/[^0-9]*$/,-999/' filename`.  This is different from the edit above (note the additional comma).

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{if($11==""){$11="-999"};print}' your.file
```

The command will set the 11th column to `-999` if it is empty

---

User `sudo_O` suggested a version of the script above that follows the same logic but looks much cleaner:

```
awk '$11==""{$11=-999}1' FS=, OFS=, your.file
```

Comment: what did not work? I have tested it with the file you posted in your question

Comment: @shodanex :) I think it is funny, that you seem to have taken the same ways to solution like me.. (and encountered the same problems with that newline).. Finally the line above did the trick for me :)

Comment: @sudo_O nice :) why not answering? it looks much cleaner than my

Comment: @sudo_O Your command is one of the reasons why I like awk so much! I so far got the expertise to understand it, but you see, my own commands can be still simplified in most cases.. will go on learning. thanks for teaching this! :)

Comment: The question has 5 other answers and mine would only be stylistically different from yours so it doesn't make much sense. That is why I love `awk` also, feel free to take my code as your answer if you so wish.

Comment: IMHO if you want to use the same value for both the FS and OFS, then setting them both concurrently to that single value using `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="whatever"}...'` is clearer and more maintainable than setting them individually both to the same value using `awk '...' FS="whatever" OFS="whatever"` or equivalent.

Comment: @EdMorton Have changed the first approach regarding your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This sed should work:

```
sed -i.bak 's/, *$/&999/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replacing `,\n` with `,-999\n`

```
sed 's/\,\n&/\,-999\n&/g' file_name
```

Comment: thank you both ( @anubhava)  but none of the proposed solution changed anything =/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use awk separator variable, something like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    OFS=",";
}
{
    if ( $11 == "") {
        print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,"-999"
    } else {
        print $0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print $0 (/,$/?-999:"")}' file
22.0,26235,-48.4,-999,-999,-999,100,22,669.0,-999,669.0
20.0,26860,-47.5,-999,-999,-999,100,21,690.0,-999,690.0
19.3,27096,-47.1,-999,-999,-999,100,21,698.3,-999,698.3
19.0,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,100,21,-999,-999,-999
```

or if you like golf:

```
$ awk '/,$/{$0=$0"-999"}1' file
22.0,26235,-48.4,-999,-999,-999,100,22,669.0,-999,669.0
20.0,26860,-47.5,-999,-999,-999,100,21,690.0,-999,690.0
19.3,27096,-47.1,-999,-999,-999,100,21,698.3,-999,698.3
19.0,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,100,21,-999,-999,-999
```

Personally, I'd just use one of the posted simple sed solutions for this, e.g. @anubhava's

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^,]+/&/11;t;s/$/-999/' file
```

If there is no eleventh field append `-999`